# Side menu like the Climate app on WPF Classic Desktop

Tags: wpf, xaml

How do I make a side menu like the Climate app?

[image]

[image]

What components, layouts and properties should I use?

Comment: If you mean UWP, not WPF, see here: [Controls list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185406.aspx). Take a closer look at SplitView.

Comment: I'm using WPF Classic Windows Desktop. It's possible?

Comment: FYI There's a chapter _Creating a Visual Studio-like Collapsable, Dockable, Resizable Pane_ in the WPF Bible "WPF 4.5 Unleashed" that teaches just what you're after. A more elaborate review, without the basics, can be found on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/439873/Simple-Visual-Studio-like-Pane-Resizing-Docking-an).

Comment: For a basic flyout, assuming those menu items are in some kind of ItemsControl, you could give the control a narrow width, then use an "IsMouseOver" trigger to increase the width to reveal the labels. More elaborate slide in/out effects can be achieved by animating the control's width (again triggered by IsMouseOver).

Comment: @AndrewStephens, It can be a simple menu component? `<menu></menu>` ?

Comment: Yes, there is no reason why it can't just be a menu control, with the items styled to look like those in the above screenshot (if that's the end result you are looking for).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Mahapps. It has nice and modern styles and a flyout control.

You can find it via nuget.

Beside the flyout it comes with other controls and control helpers sich as watermarks for textboxes.